# Pass regular expression as script argument Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to pass regular expression to process a file line by line. The regular expression works fine if I hard code it in the code, like this.

```
File.foreach(filename).with_index do |line, line_num|
  md5 = line.scan(/[0-9a-f]{32}/i)
  puts md5
end
```

This works wonderful and I can see every line that has a MD5 hash on it printed. Now, the problem comes when I try to pass the regular expression to match md5 hashes as a script argument like:

`ruby md5.rb -h "/[0-9a-f]{32}/i"`

```
options = {}
OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.on('-h', '--hash "<hash regex>"', 'Hash Regex') { |v| options[:hash] = v }
end.parse!

hash = options[:hash]
File.foreach(filename).with_index do |line, line_num|
  md5 = line.scan(hash)
  puts md5
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the inside bits of the regex as a string, then convert it to a regex later eg:

```
ruby md5.rb -h "[0-9a-f]{32}"
```

To convert a string into a regex, just use interpolation:

```
regex = /#{regex_string}/i
```

Comment: Instead of interpolation, you could also use `Regexp.new(regex_string)` which will throw a `RegexpError` if the expression is invalid.